# concatinating 2 pandas dataframes does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes of size 31789x7 and 31789x3. I want to create a 31789x10 dataframe. This works in principle with

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

for artificial data in half a second. But on my data the concat does not finish within 10 min. If I do it "manually" with:

```
for c in df2:
    df1[c] = df2[c]
```

it crashed with:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

What is the problem here? (ignore_index=True does not help)

Comment: I'm confused, you're issue is that `pd.concat` is taking a long time?  Or that your for loop is throwing an error?  In either event a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `reindex` and assign the value only

```
df1=df1.reindex(columns=list(df2)+list(df1))
df1[list(df2)]=df2.values
```

Comment: @jezrael yep that is true , cause the np.array only can keep one type

Answer (score 1):

One idea is create default `RangeIndex` first:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), 
                 df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

---

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

for c in df2:
    df1[c] = df2[c]
```

Af same types of all columns (e.g. `integer`s), use [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
c = df1.columns.append(df2.columns)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((df1.values, df2.values)), columns=c)
```